# JavaCV на другом компьютере

Tags: java, opencv

Как перенести программу, написанную при помощи JavaCV на компьютер, на котором не установлено ни JavaCV, ни OpenCV ? Желательно, при этом, конвертировав в exe.

Answer (score 1):

Просто при экспорте программы в jar, указываешь что библиотеки, которые используются в проекте, запихивать в этот экспортируемый файл. Потом конвертируешь в exe например вот [такой](http://www.jar2exe.com/) прогой (хотя я не уверен, что она компилит в бинарник, которому не нужна jre).